# get only available simple products of configurable product

Tags: php, magento

I am using below piece of code

```
$configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
                $simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
                $productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
                $attributeOptions = array();
                foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {

                        foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
                            $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][] = 
                            array('id' => $attribute['value_index'],
                                'label' => $attribute['label'],
                                'mainId' => $productAttribute['attribute_id'] );
                        }

                    }


            return $attributeOptions;
```

but it gives me list of all simple product even those are not available in stock.
I just want list of simple product of a configurable product those are in stock.
How can i get only in stock products of a configurable product

Comment: How about using a where statement to select products where they are in stock?

Answer (score 0):

You can check product stock status `0`- not in stock or `1` - in stock

```
$configurable= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simpleCollection = $configurable->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
/* -------- Add this  ------- */
$simpleCollection->getSelect()->join('cataloginventory_stock_status', 'cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = e.entity_id', array('stock_status'));
$simpleCollection->getSelect()->where("`cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` = 1");

$productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {

        foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
            $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']][] = 
            array('id' => $attribute['value_index'],
                'label' => $attribute['label'],
                'mainId' => $productAttribute['attribute_id'] );
        }

    }


return $attributeOptions;
```

Comment: but it still gives me all options @vky

Comment: My friend check your question `get only available simple products of configurable product` so I gave a solution for that.

Comment: i modified code and use it accordingly so it worked, Thanks